# delete everything between two tags using bash

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to make uninstaller for my script. Problem is that in the same file i have multiple commands from other things, so i need to get just portion of that script. I divide that portion with tags

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "other code"
# Other code

#test
tempCommandFile=$(mktemp)
function btmonTemp() {
    rm -rf $tempCommandFile
}
echo "Uninstall process"
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.app.plist 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/paveljame/app 
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.app.plist 
sudo rm -rf /var/log/script/app 
echo "Finished" 
echo '#!/bin/bash
tempFinisedFile=$(mktemp)
awk "/#test/{p=1;print}/#endtest/{p=0}!p" /usr/local/bin/script > $tempFinisedFile
cat $tempFinisedFile > /usr/local/bin/script
rm -rf $tempFinisedFile 
rm -rf $tempCommandFile
' > $tempCommandFile
#endtest
sh $tempCommandFile
trap btmonTemp EXIT
```

After running the script, i'm getting this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "other code"
# Other code

#test
awk "/#test/{p=1;print}/#endtest/{p=0}!p" /usr/local/bin/script > $tempFinisedFile
awk "/#test/{p=1;print}/#endtest/{p=0}!p" /usr/local/bin/script > $tempFinisedFile
cat $tempFinisedFile > /usr/local/bin/script
rm -rf $tempFinisedFile 
rm -rf $tempCommandFile
' > $tempCommandFile
#endtest
sh $tempCommandFile
trap btmonTemp EXIT
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: You might want to consider a `heredoc`.

Comment: That will probably help me out here,  but how can i user heredoc inside of the heredoc? :D I need that in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can test your code with

```
awk "/#test/{p=1;print}/#endtest/{p=0}!p" /usr/local/bin/script
```

The output shows the `awk` command twice. Why?
It will print a line when somewhere in the line it finds `#test`.
A match is found in the line with `awk`.
Fix: add `^`:

```
awk "/^#test/{p=1;print}/^#endtest/{p=0}!p" /usr/local/bin/script
```

Comment: -bash: !p": event not found
Im getting this when i trying that command

Comment: Replace the `awk` command with ` awk "/#test/{p=1} /#endtest/{p=0} p==1{print}"   /usr/local/bin/script`

Comment: `#test
    tempCommandFile=$(mktemp)
    function btmonTemp() {
        rm -rf $tempCommandFile
    }
    echo "Uninstall process"
    sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com. app.plist
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/script/app
    sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.app.plist
    sudo rm -rf /var/log/script/app
    echo "Finished"
    echo '#!/bin/bash
    tempFinisedFile=$(mktemp)`
This is the output that i got. So he delete everything out of tags and just part of code inside the tags. Btw ty for your help

Comment: You can use this in your script. If it answers your question you can accept this answer. (V)

Comment: Problem is that you answer doesnt solve my case. I want to remove everything between two tags, and most of content inside the tag is still there. Your solution delelite just part of tag content, and everything else outside of tags. If i switch from  ` awk "/#test/{p=1} /#endtest/{p=0} p==1{print}" /usr/local/bin/script` to  ` awk "/#test/{p=1} /#endtest/{p=0} p==0{print}" /usr/local/bin/script` in that case, everything outside of tag is good, but still big portion of content inside of the tag is visible

Comment: Better to use single quotes `awk '/^#test/{p=1;print}/^#endtest/{p=0}!p' /usr/local/bin/script` (solves error on `!p`, the exclamation mark is special on the command line).

Comment: Replace `awk "/#test/{p=1} /#endtest/{p=0} p==1{print}" /usr/local/bin/script` with `awk "/^#test/{p=1} /^#endtest/{p=0} p==1{print}" /usr/local/bin/script` to avoid the awk command in the script triggering the `p`-flag.